# Spacebar only adding space in between letters

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I am trying to implement an instance of the CKEditor WYSIWYG. I am running it in a Vue 2.x application.
I have downloaded the source files for the CKEditor (https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue2/blob/master/dist/ckeditor.js) and ClassicEditor (https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/31.0.0/classic/ckeditor.js) dist files downloaded and served to my page. The console confirms these two are being loaded correctly.
The problem is that the editor doesn't register spaces unless they are in-between two letters.
Here is the relevant code-

View.php

```
        Vue.use(window.CKEditor)
        new Vue({
            el: '#components-demo',
            data: {
                editor: window.ClassicEditor,
                editorConfig: {
                    width: '100%',
                    height: '100%'
                }
            }
        })
    </script>
```

Component.js

```
Vue.component('userNotesEditor', {
    template: /*template*/ `
    <div id="editor-main">
       <ckeditor :editor="Classic" v-model="content" :config="config"></ckeditor>
    </div>
    `,
    components: {
        ckeditor: window.CKEditor.component
    },
    props: {
    },
    data: function() {
        return {
            content: '',
            options: {},
            Classic: window.ClassicEditor,
        }
    },
```

The editor loads- [image: ![CKEditor WYSIWYG]
And adds HTML markup correctly- [image: ![Vue Devtools Content]

But, pressing spacebar only yields a space if the cursor is between words; Also, it doesn't let me add multiple consecutive spaces even when placing them between letters. I am not sure why that is and I have not found any relevant resources.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the '<p>&nbsp;</p>' thats created automatically with a string space (' ')